# page mim type png - uploading/open dialog loads php/text file

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, png, mime-types

I'm working on a small project to generate dynamic images. Currently I have troubles with page mime type or something similar.

For example, a minimalistic PHP code

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$img = imagecreatefrompng("https://i.ibb.co/PZ9C4pF/1629585581.png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

I can call the PHP page in browser and can see the image as preferred. Until here everything looks good.

Than, for example I go to Evernote and upload a document. In "open" window dialog for choosing the file, I paste in the same URL as in browser before. (Yes in windows open explorer you can paste in urls.) After some seconds there is a file uploaded called "index.php" and inside this file is the PNG image string.

[image]

If I paste in other urls which generates images at running time (for example `https://via.placeholder.com/150`) it uploads an image and not a PHP or text file

Many thanks for your help - I'm sure the solution is quick and easy. ☺

Comment: *a file uploaded called "index.php"* you would need to use rewrites and make sure the extension is .png, Evernote is naming the file .php then its going to not treat it like an image

Comment: @LawrenceCherone This was my first thought as well, the example he used at `placeholder.com` has no file extension so Evernote is probably doing a naive check if it sees an extension name and a mime type check for no extension.